# Language file/lib/extension ( .ENG, .ITA, .FRA, etc)

Tags: file-extension

Does anyone have experience with these file extensions: `.ENG` for English, `.ITA` for Italian and so on?

I have program written in C/C++ which uses these files to change the language of the application. If I try to open it with Notepad, to correct some words for my language, I see the same thing as when I open a binary file.

Is that file type equivalent with `.bin`? If can someone give me reference how this system works? When I worked apps with multiple language support, I had to use database and from there calling words depending on which language is chosen. So how does it work with this extension language files?

Comment: This depends entirely on the application using these files, which you have not named. Maybe use `file` to check whether it is a documented format with a header such as .zip?

Comment: It is uncommon to have a special file suffix per language. You could, however, use a second level suffix like `file.en.txt` or `file.it.txt`, so applications assign the correct mime type based on the top level suffix.

Comment: Program is not mainstream so name could not help. That's some old program for translating a software which is on microcontroller over rs232 communication. I assumed they used some of known technics for language support

Comment: I tied to change it to .txt, that gives me same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends entirely on the application using these files which you have not named. `.bin` is also just a name that doesn't indicate for sure what such files contain.

Comment: Well, thank you for answer. I thought it is maybe some common way to do language support...but it's unfortunately not. So i would better check app for some additional informations... Thanks anyway